# Pentaho: How to put multiple cells in same row?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am asked to design a report with displaying multiple cells in a row, to make better usage of the space.
For example, my query would return some thing like this:

```
Name   Count
n1      2
n2      3
n3      4
```

And what I would like to display in the report is:

```
Name    Count    Name    Count     Name    Count
n1        2       n2       3       n3        4
```

Is there a good way to handle that?
Thanks all

Comment: which tool are you using?
pentaho report designer ?
and your output does not make sense.

Comment: yes, pentaho designer. Not sure what u mean by "my output does not make sense". But the point I was trying to make is that the query outputs only contains 2 columns, and on the report, it would leave a large place of blank on the right of the data it displays. That's why I would like to see if there's way I can "make a better usage of the space" for the report

Comment: There is a concept called sub-report where you can create such structure but it is not a good practice, when one is generating tabular report such issue occurs so you can use different formatting,look and fill,putting shadow box type of  changes but there is no meaning of changing structure.